# How to authenticate user with AWS Cognito in Vue.js using Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, amazon-cognito

I am facing the issue that I cannot fully undertsand how to call a function that uses a callback and get the results of the callback returned in a way where the data from the response becomes available to a Vue application.

```
async loginUser(username, password) {
        AWS.config.update({region : region});

        const payload = {
            AuthFlow: "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
            ClientId: clientId,
            AuthParameters : {
                USERNAME: username,
                PASSWORD: password
            }
        }
    
        var cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
        return cognito.initiateAuth(payload, function(err,data) {
            if (err) {
                alert("Error: " + err);
                return null;
            }
            else {
                tokenData = data["AuthenticationResult"];
                console.log(tokenData);
                return tokenData;
            }
        })
    }
```

I want the tokenData to be what is returned when calling loginUser, but no matter what I try to do the data from the cognito.initiateAuth, that should be used in my application to validate a sign in, will just be null and not usable.

Hope you guys can help!
Thanks

I tried different solutions using promises, async/await, while loops trying to wait for the response to contain data, but nothing seems to work. I can see the data being printed correctly in the callback, but how do it get this data to pass on to the return of loginUser.

Comment: Hi NicolarDige there might be few things wrong, but I think that I would check few things: is "data" empty, do you have everything that is required in the payload that you are sending, are you getting something in the "err". Also the AWS docs are sometimes a little cryptic, so no worries. When I was trying to do something with AWS I was opting for AWS amplify which streamlines the process of building with AWS services

Comment: Also from docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#getUser-property) I see that the AuthenticationResult might only get returned if "...if the caller doesn't need to pass another challenge. If the caller does need to pass another challenge before it gets tokens, ChallengeName, ChallengeParameters, and Session are returned". Maybe this is it